# How to get the name of the file which imported me?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Let us supposed the there are the modules A, B, C:

**A.py**

```
import C
# do stuff
```

**B.py**

```
import C
# do stuff
```

**C.py**

```
print( "I am the C module and I am being imported by " + get_importer_name() )
```

Then when running `A.py` or `B.py` the output would be:

```
 I am the C module and I am being imported by A
 I am the C module and I am being imported by B
```

Does exists something like the `get_importer_name()` function, which gets the name of the module which imported me (supposing I am a module)?